# libpng.14.so.14 not found but is installed on SUSE

Tags: opensuse, libpng, suse

im trying to run LS-OPT UI 5.2.1 on my OpenSUSE system.
it tells me the following:

```
./lsoptui: error while loading shared libraries: libpng14.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But `libpng14.so.14` is installed in `/usr/lib`

Whats the Problem here?
Do i have to link it somehow?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your program is trying to search for the library somewhere different. I recommend trying to run your binary with `strace`.  You should be able to see where the binary is looking at.  At the place you should create symbolic link to the installed library.